# Django file structure for downloaded theme

Tags: python, django

[image]

I am experimenting with django and bootstrap3. I haven't used the template portions of django so this may be a simplistic question. My django file structure looks pretty vanilla, please see the screenshot.

I have found an interesting theme I'd like to use which I've downloaded from http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/landing-page/ .  The file structure looks like the second screenshot:

[image]

What is the best file structure to use this in a django project?

Comment: that are just a bunch of css, js and html files, you put them as usual where other django assets and templates are placed, what bothers you?

Comment: I've read through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ , but I'm not totally clear on the common approaches people take to manage their static files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your project has a structure like (showing only relevant files to ease the understanding of what I'm talking about):

```
projectname
    appname
        models.py
        views.py
    projectname
        wsgi.py
        urls.py
        settings.py
```

Usually you will create a `static` and `templates` in your parent `projectname` directory, and in each of these you put an `appname` dir, where you put app specific assets or templates:

```
projectname
    appname
        models.py
        views.py
    static
         css
             main.css
         js
             main.js
         appname
             css
             js
    templates
         index.html
         appname
             appname_list.html
    projectname
        wsgi.py
        urls.py
        settings.py
```

I hope the structure is clear from here, then you put your bootstrap index.html in templates/ dir, modifying the assets inclusion with links to `{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}` and `{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}`.

Also I should point out that usually things like [`django-pipeline`](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are really useful in assets minification, concatenation, and compression.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your CSS/JS/Fonts/Etc files under yourApp/static/, then put all the html under templates.

In your HTML, use relative paths to your css/js files or use django template language to bring it in.

Comment: regarding the HTML : templates within my app or within the project?

Comment: It does not matter where you put it, it depends on the purpose. I put the html in the app/templates folder to simplify it in my head. But if you are planning to use that code as base HTML and not edit it much, you may want to put in the project folder.

Comment: you should really *always* use the {% static %} tag to manage static assets in the template.

Comment: because good practices are there for a reason! More precisely because it ease you if you change your structure between local or production environment, or decide that a cdn like amazon s3 is better for scaling purposes, all without touching a single line in your templates.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers and discussion. This helps me - Bill